# Save values from a Textbox to an excel sheet based on combobox selection VBA

Tags: vba, combobox, userform

I have another issue. I am trying to save the values of textboxes on a userform to an excel worksheet so they can be retained when userform is closed then re-opened.

I have a combobox(procNamecombobox) that is populated from sheet("DailyNumbers")from Column "A".  On the same sheet I have columns B to E that will keep record of the number of processed items by each person from column "A". The value of these records are stored in textboxes on the userform when the processor hits submit. 

**What my aim is:** Depending on the selection of the combobox(procNamecombobox) I would like the values from the textboxes on the userform to save on the worksheet("DailyNumbers") to columns B-E for the row that matches the combobox seclection.

**Example:**

A1 = Name(combobox/selection); B1= textbox1.Value; C1=textbox2.Value; D1= textbox3.Value and E1= textbox4.Value 

A2 = Name(combobox/selection); B2= textbox1.Value; C2=textbox2.Value; D2= textbox3.Value and E2= textbox4.Value 

...and so on

This will continue down the combobox.List ("A2:A")

Hope that makes sense! 

Thank you!

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I am not sure how to start the code that allows me to populate the spreadsheet with the values from the textboxes into a specific row based on the combobox selection

Comment: I's start by using `Find()` to locate the correct row, by matching the combobox selection against column A.

Comment: So, I have this so far but it doesn't seem to be right...

Comment: If you're adding code then edit your question - it's not going to be useful in a comment.